# XCode 4.0.0 Version instead of Xcode 4.0.2

Tags: xcode, repository

I downloaded Xcode 4.0.2 just a while back. I am not able to connect to the repositories as I was able to do in Xcode 4.0.0.

I do not know the reason for this, and I think the settings are pretty much right. I am now searching for Xcode 4.0.0 so that I could revert back to the earlier version.

Does anybody know where I can find the earlier version of Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look on torrent sites, there may be some out there. Also, try searching Google for links from Apple, you may be able to figure out the download link from the most recent available on Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Time Machine? You could revert to an earlier version from there.